# Cypress parallelization: is there a way to access the current parallel run instance within the test in order to use different users for each instance?

Tags: parallel-processing, cypress

I am looking at using the cypress `parallel = true` option to run tests in parallel through github actions. I currently run tests in parallel a different way and to ensure the parallel instances do not interfere with each other (as am using API to set up and clear down test data at the start of tests etc), I have an environment variable `'testRunName'` which I use within a username (e.g. `user1${testRunName}@whatever.io`, `user2${testRunName}@whatever.io`, etc) to ensure each parallel test run instance logs in as different users, thereby ensuring the runs do not interfere with each other. My current method of parallelisation is somewhat limited as I have to hardcode the tests which go into each run and I would like to try out the cypress `parallel = true` option so that the tests get distributed more intelligently across the different machines.

I am not sure if I will be able to control environment variables like my `'testRunName'` in this way if I use the Cypress `parallel = true` option and the documentation does not talk about pointing to different databases or user instances or how to achieve that unless I am missing something!

I basically need to know the instance of the parallel run e.g. "0", "1", "2" etc to be able to build up my unique `testRunName` and set this for each parallel instance. Is this even possible? It must be the same name each time as otherwise my tests will keep creating new test users for each run and we have a limit on the number of test users we can generate each month.

A similar thing was possible back in the day when I used to use cucumber selenium to run tests in parallel - basically they made an environment variable `PARALLEL_INSTANCE`  ( = 0, 1, 2, 3 etc) available to the test code so you could use this to do things like point to different databases or user instances.

Answer (score 0):

So from playing around and setting up a workflow to run cypress parallel true through github actions, I have worked out how to set my testRunName to include the instance of the paralllel run. Basically you can use ${{ matrix.containers }}. E.g:

```js
.
.
.
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        containers: [1, 2, 3]
    steps
    .
    .
    .
      - name: Cypress regression run
      uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
      with:
        browser: chrome
        headless: true
        env: xxxxxxxxx
        config: xxxxxxxx
        spec: xxxxxxxxx
        record: true
        parallel: true
      env:
        CYPRESS_testRunName: parallel${{ matrix.containers }}
        CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
```